# Query with double group by?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to edit this query:

```
SELECT (WEEKDAY( date ) +1) dayofweek, COUNT( * ) count 
FROM abanners 
WHERE iid = ? AND banner LIKE ? 
GROUP BY (WEEKDAY( date ) +1) 
ORDER BY count DESC
```

With this query I get the number of entries splited by day of week, but what if I need to get the same thing splitted also by `banner`?

So I want to have:

```
 banner1: entries splitted by day of week
 banner2: entries splitted by day of week

 ex: {"banner1" : "1,3,4,1,3,5,1", "banner2": "1,3,4,1,3,5,1"}
```

How can I do?

Comment: Just add `banner` to both the `SELECT` list and to the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: In this way it gives me: `array ('dayofweek' => '1','COUNT( * )' => '4', 'count' => 'banner1')`

Comment: `banner` must come before the weekday in `GROUP BY`.  (also, you can just use the alias `dayofweek` in the `GROUP BY` - you don't need the full expression in MySQL as you would with SQL Server for example

Comment: thanks with `banner` before the rest it works!

Comment: I'll put an answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To accomplish this, you only need to add `banner` to both the `SELECT` list and to the `GROUP BY`.  However, it must come before the `dayofweek` expression in the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT 
  banner,
  (WEEKDAY( date ) +1) dayofweek,
  COUNT(*) count
FROM abanners
WHERE 
  iid = ? 
  AND banner LIKE ?
GROUP BY
  banner,
  dayofweek
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Note that I have used the alias `dayofweek` in the `GROUP BY` here. MySQL permits aliases in the `GROUP BY` where some other RDBMS will report an error there.